# Selecting a particular tag using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

```
<table class="striped">
<tbody>
     <tr><td><img src="images/google.png"/>&nbsp;Google Indexed Pages</td><td class="right">613000000</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="images/dmoz.png"/>&nbsp;dmoz Directory Listed</td><td class="right">Yes</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="images/pagerank.png"/>&nbsp;Google Page Rank</td><td class="right">9/10</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to extract google rank value i.e *9/10* using jsoup.

This is the code i have written till now

```
Element tbody = doc.select("tbody>tr>td>img[src=images/pagerank.png]").first();
```

How could i move to next tag after this  ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by move to next tag? The next google page rank tag?

The select method of document tag actually returns an Elements object which is essentially an implementation of List. So you could iterate throught that to get next elements. If you want another element you could use doc.select again.

```
for (Element e : doc.select("tbody>tr>td>img[src=images/pagerank.png]")) {
    //your code.
}
```